# A better word than "disabled"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, expression-choice

I have recently completed a 'Lean' project on enhancing customer experience in a Hospice.
Before submitting my report, I was taking a stock of the various signage at the hospital.

A few of them read as follows:

- Wheel-Chair-Area
- Disabled batch holders only
- Spastic Center
- Disabled people

Are there some commonly-identified-substitute words which would appear politically correct and does not emphasize on the impairment?

Comment: I assume by ***batch*** in your second example you mean ***badge***. In the UK the only credible alternative to ***disabled*** there would be [**Blue Badge**](https://www.gov.uk/apply-blue-badge). A lot of people would get *very* annoyed if you used any other terminology, on the grounds that it's feasible some "entitled" people might not understand it. But any alternatives are all a matter of opinion anyway.

Comment: I assume that anyone with mobility issues would qualify, not just actual cripples, right?

Comment: Isn't in important to be **specific** in a hospital? It is a bit late to find out an area is not wheelchair accessible after you get there...like a flight of stairs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am disabled and I suggest not using **differently-abled**; I really don't like the word. I recommend **handicapped** if you really don't want to use **disabled**.

EDIT: Also I think the government calls them 'handicap placards" or "disabled persons placards" (the blue placards that you hang in your car) anyway.

> Be aware that many people with disabilities dislike jargony, euphemistic terms like "physically challenged" and "differently abled."

[I don't really agree with everything here but it could be helpful.](http://www.inclusionsolutions.com/Advocacy/disability-etiquette.html)

Answer (score 3):

> People with disabilities dislike jargony, euphemistic terms like
>   “physically challenged”, “differently-abled” 
>   and “disability.”

•Disabled people/the disabled: person with a disability or people with disabilities.

•Spastic Center: or Center for Cerebral Palsy

•Wheel-Chair-Area : I saw a signage in a Korean Hospital- "Enabling Logistics".

*(wheel-chairs enable movement)*

•Disabled batch holders only: If there's a batch color, use it. E.g. Blue badge holders only

> It was ability that mattered, not disability, which is a word I'm not  crazy about using.”
>   - Marlee Matlin

Comment: As someone who had a temporary "visual impairment" (blindness) I can tell you that some of the p.c. words and phrases are upsetting. At the hospital the phrase they used to mean blindness was "low vision" and it was more confusing than anything else. Personally, having been "differently-abled" for a while I hate the phrase. It is meant to be empowering but is really patronizing. There is nothing "abled" about haing trouble crossing the street.

Comment: @ValerieClark Isn't "low vision" meant to include also those who aren't blind, but still have poor enough eyesight to be disabled by it?

Comment: Or very short people...

Answer (score 2):

The term *special needs* is often used to reflect accommodations of various types.

Also the term *accessibility* is often used to focus on the actual field which requires modification to assist people with who may have special needs. It can be combined to reflect the actual adjustment as in *accessibility enhanced* (or *enhancement*), *accessibility modified*,  or simply *accessibility accommodations*.

Answer (score 1):

- Wheel-chair-Area

I think that mechanically-assisted-transportation area would work here

- Disabled batch [sic] holders only and Disabled People

Area reserved for certified differently-abled personnel

Comment: +1, I pondered over 'differently-abled'..fits in.